# How to run executable jar in other systems?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, executable-jar

I have scripted a selenium web driver program in java on eclipse IDE.

This program gets the data from a excel sheet placed on my systems desktop and all the jars are added in the build path from my desktop.

```
EXAMPLE:C:\Users\PEOPLE\Desktop\selenium-server-2.53.0\selenium-2.53.0\libs.
```

The entire program is exported into a runnable jar file and placed on the desktop.

The jar file is working fine as expected.

Now the question is how to make jar file run in other systems?

what are the pre requisites to make jar file run in other system?

Comment: Please explain me  the scenario that you want to run your jar from remote system or you are talking about other OS. if other OS then  As Java is os independent  but JVM is dependent on OS so your jar file will run on any OS but you must install JRE specific to OS.

Comment: This question really isn't clear what it is asking. Imagine you were someone else reading this question. What are the actual problems you are having running the program. What have you tried. How is it working fine on your system but not on another?

Comment: It is same OS .

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not clear. I have exported my Java program into a jar file.  And the program gets input from Excel sheet. Now I need to run this jar file in other computer with same OS . How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things mainly:

1. A Java JRE installed so that you can run `java -jar yourJar.jar` or 
   `java -classpath yourJar.jar your.package.name.MainClass`
2. A way to configure the path for loading your Excel sheet (specially if the path is different on the other system). For instance, you could read this path in your Java program from a configuration text file `app.config` located in the same repository of your jar.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the same path for the Excel file as is in your system (else you need to edit the Config file) along with the name of the file.Now, just install the latest JRE in the system and you should be good to go.